# Index of array becomes "length"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small snippet that is causing me some issues:

```
var selectedComponents = $("#tab3 input:checked");

for (var s in selectedComponents)
```

I have a breakpoint right inside the for-loop. The list contains 2 elements so at first `s` is `0` then `1` then `length`?

There are only two elements which is correct, but why `length`?

Comment: Because for-in loops loop through the keys of an object, which one of them is `length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `for in` loop will give you all properties that are marked with property attribute `enumerable`. In your case you haven't an array but jQuery array like object. For array it will give you the indexes and other properties which are enumerable.

Don't use `for in` loop to iterate over array. Use [**for of (ES6)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), **[Array.forEach() (ES5.1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** or simple `for` loop

```js
const array = [1,2,3];

// With for of
for(let item of array) {
   console.log(item);
}
 
// With forEach method
array.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: Wow, I did not realize that! Mind blown. Guess I have to check if the property is an int, if (s !== parseInt(s, 10))

Comment: Any suggestion to iterate over the selection?

Comment: If you use ES6 or higher you can check `for of` loop or `forEach` method, otherwise you need simple for loop

Comment: To clarify, `selectedComponents` isn’t an array, it’s a jQuery object with the three enumerable properties `0`, `1` and `length`. Thus, `forEach` also won’t work. jQuery actually has its own `each` method for that.

Comment: @fUrious No, don't check for numbers (JavaScript doesn't have `int`). Just use the correct type of loop.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan `.forEach()` is ES5, not ES6.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated, a `for/in` loop is meant to loop through objects with a `key/value` data structure. The keys are strings that represent the property names and the values are the actual data stored with those keys.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)**:

> A for...in loop only iterates over enumerable properties. Objects
>   created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have
>   inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and
>   String.prototype, such as String's indexOf() method or Object's
>   toString() method. The loop will iterate over all enumerable
>   properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its
>   constructor's prototype (properties closer to the object in the
>   prototype chain override prototypes' properties).

An array doesn't have string-based keys, it has numeric indices an, as such, a `for/in` loop shouldn't be used to iterate through it because it will loop over *all* the properties of the object that are configured to be enumerable. As you are seeing that is the indexes as well as the `length`.

```js
var myArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

// for/in loops loop over the string key names of an object
// Arrays don't have these, so their indexes are coverted to strings
// This is not only slower than numeric access, but this type of loop
// iterates all the properties (keys), not just the indexes.
for(var item in myArray) {
  console.log(myArray[item], "(Enumertor is a: " + typeof item + ")");
}
```

For arrays, you should loop using a traditional counting type loop:

```js
var myArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

// With a counting loop, you only iterate over the indexes
// and you do it with number types (faster than strings)
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i], "(Enumertor is a: " + typeof i + ")");
}
```

Or, even better (because you don't have to mess with counters) the **[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method:

```js
var myArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

// forEach is built to only iterate the indexes of an array
// but allows us to do it without having to set up or maintain
// any counters.
myArray.forEach(function(value){
  console.log(value);
});
```